# Differences between style hidden, block and none

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out the differences between style

- hidden
- block
- none

I am trying with this example, but unfortunately this isn't working.
Could anybody please let me know the answer?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Unleashed</title>

<script>
  function callMe()
  {

  document.getElementById('layer1').style.visibility = 'block';
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="callMe()">


  <div name="layer1">

  <hr>DIV 1<hr>

  </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try document.getElementById('layer1').style.display = 'block'; and document.getElementById('layer1').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're really close. Two different properties.

```
display: (block || none) (there are more options here)
visibility: (visible || hidden)
```

The different is with `display:none` the element is completely hidden from the view. So if you have a box with 300px height and width then you would not see anything there.

With `visibility:hidden` it will keep the dimensions of the area, but will hide all the content.

Answer (score 1):

Block isn't a valid visibility option. You are thinking of the Display property which can be set to block.

[Visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

[Display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It should be style.display for "block" and "none" to work. Visibility reserves space for the element on the page while, display:none doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) for full reference and examples on the difference between different styles decalrations. (hidden relates to visibility)

Basically:

display: block

display: block means that the element is displayed as a block, as paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another element, for instance).

display: none

display: none means that the element is not displayed at all (so you won't see it in the example either).

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements in CSS style: `visibility` and `display`.  Visibility may be `hidden` or `visible` (or `collapse` for tables).  Display may be `inline`, `block` or `none`.

The main difference between `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` is that in the second case the content still takes spaces on the page for layout purposes, but is not visible, however with `display: none` the content is removed from the layout altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There are two css styles you are confusing:

`visibility` which can be set to `visible` or `hidden` - this hides the object without removing it from the flow, which means that the formatting of the page will be unchanged.

`display` which can be many things including: `block`, `inline`, `none`.

Setting `display:none` also hides an element, but it also removes it from the page flow, meaning surrounding elements can be affected as they "fill" the hole.

Answer (score 0):

for hiding document element

```
 document.getElementById('layer1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

that can also be achieved by

```
 document.getElementById('layer1').style.display = 'none';
```

so for showing you do

```
 document.getElementById('layer1').style.display = 'block';
```

or

```
 document.getElementById('layer1').style.visibility = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

while defining the div you just need to add the style property as below

```
<div id="layer1" style="disply:none" >
</div>
```

and while using in function

```
document.getElementById("layer1").style.display = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following modified code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Unleashed</title>

<script>
  function callMe()
  {
    document.getElementById("layer1").style.display = "none";
  }
function resetElement()
{
  document.getElementById("layer1").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Heading </h1>
  <div id="layer1">
  <button onclick="callMe()">click to hide</button>
    <hr>DIV 1<hr>
  </div>
  <div>
  <button onclick="resetElement()">Reset All</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.