# how to take out gap between input tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement to display additional input tags based on user radio tag. I pasted the working code here. I wanted to display spouse first name and last name input tags. If not, will have to display father and mother first and last name. But problem is, I see a gap in between, which I don't want. Any help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function check() {
      if (document.getElementById('Married').checked) 
      {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
      else
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  </script>
  <form>
    First Name <input type="text" id="UserFirstName" value="Your First Name"> 
    Last Name <input type="text" id="UserLastName" value="Your Last Name"></br></br>
    Marital Status <input type="radio" id="Married" name="MarStatus" onclick="javascript:check();" >Married <input type="radio" id="UnMarried" name="MarStatus" onclick="javascript:check();">UnMarried </br></br>

     <div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
    Spouse First Name <input type="text" id="SpouseFirstName" value="Spouse First Name">   
    Last Name <input type="text" id="SpouseLastName" value="Spouse Last Name"></br></br>
    </div>
    Father First Name <input type="text" id="FatherFirstName" value="Father First Name"> Last Name <input type="text" id="FatherLastName" value="Father Last Name"></br></br>
    Mother First Name <input type="text" id="FatherFirstName" value="Mother First Name"> Last Name <input type="text" id="FatherLastName" value="Mother Last Name"></br>
    </br>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='b.php'">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between style hidden, block and none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651939/differences-between-style-hidden-block-and-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced `visibility:hidden` by `display:none`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function check() {
 if (document.getElementById('Married').checked) 
 {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
 }
 else
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<form>
First Name <input type="text" id="UserFirstName" value="Your First Name"> 
Last Name <input type="text" id="UserLastName" value="Your Last Name"></br></br>
Marital Status <input type="radio" id="Married" name="MarStatus" onclick="javascript:check();" >Married <input type="radio" id="UnMarried" name="MarStatus" onclick="javascript:check();">UnMarried </br></br>

 <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
Spouse First Name <input type="text" id="SpouseFirstName" value="Spouse First Name">   
Last Name <input type="text" id="SpouseLastName" value="Spouse Last Name"></br></br>
</div>
Father First Name <input type="text" id="FatherFirstName" value="Father First Name"> Last Name <input type="text" id="FatherLastName" value="Father Last Name"></br></br>
Mother First Name <input type="text" id="FatherFirstName" value="Mother First Name"> Last Name <input type="text" id="FatherLastName" value="Mother Last Name"></br>
</br>
<button onclick="window.location.href='b.php'">Submit</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I updated my code based on suggestion made here and it works like charm. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 4):

> `visibility:hidden` will keep the element in the page and ***occupies that space*** but does not show to the user.
>
> `display:none` will not be available in the page and ***does not occupy any space***.

You should use `display:none`.

Also you are using `</br>` wrongly, should be `<br/>` or simply `<br>`. Though I suggest you not to use that. Instead you can wrap the related information with `div` element and use css to set the style (*margin* property).

Another issue is you should use the *value* attribute in the radio button based on which you can set the style inside the function.

Try the following way:

```html
<script>
  function check(el) {
    if (el.value == "Married") {
      document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
      document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
<form>
  <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    First Name <input type="text" id="UserFirstName" value="Your First Name"> 
    Last Name <input type="text" id="UserLastName" value="Your Last Name">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    Marital Status <input type="radio" value="Married" name="MarStatus" onclick="javascript:check(this);" >Married <input type="radio" value="UnMarried" name="MarStatus" onclick="javascript:check(this);">UnMarried 
  </div>

  <div id="ifYes" style="display:none; margin-bottom:20px;">
    Spouse First Name <input type="text" id="SpouseFirstName" value="Spouse First Name">   
    Last Name <input type="text" id="SpouseLastName" value="Spouse Last Name">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    Father First Name <input type="text" id="FatherFirstName" value="Father First Name"> Last Name <input type="text" id="FatherLastName" value="Father Last Name">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    Mother First Name <input type="text" id="FatherFirstName" value="Mother First Name"> Last Name <input type="text" id="FatherLastName" value="Mother Last Name">
  </div>
  <button onclick="window.location.href='b.php'">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`